# Flutter - Open weather map: Got current weather. How can I get forecast for next days?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, openweathermap, flutter-bloc

I am trying to fetch the weather forecast for each day, but I'M unable to determine which index I should use to fetch the temperature.

To get current weather temperature, I'm doing this:

```
activity.list[0].main.temp.toInt()
```

home_bloc:

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  final GetWeatherService _getWeatherService;

  HomeBloc(this._getWeatherService) : super(HomeLoadingState()) {
    on<LoadApiEvent>((event, emit) async {
      // TODO: implement event handler
      emit(HomeLoadingState());
      final activity = await _getWeatherService.getWeather();

      var sunRise =
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(activity.city.sunrise * 1000);

      var sunSet =
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(activity.city.sunset * 1000);

      emit(HomeLoadedState(
        activity.city.name.toString(),
        activity.list[0].main.temp.toInt(),
        activity.list[0].weather[0].main.toString(),
        {sunRise.hour: sunRise.minute},
        {sunSet.hour: sunSet.minute},
      ));
    });
  }
}
```

How would you approach to get the temperature for each day besides today. I would like to have a 5 day forecast NOT hourly.

[Complete json Response](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=-1.3160165&lon=36.8433088&units=metric&appid=617fd39e249c165f876869ae0330f30a)

Classes:

```
class GetWeatherDetails {
  GetWeatherDetails({
    required this.cod,
    required this.message,
    required this.cnt,
    required this.list,
    required this.city,
  });

  String cod;
  int message;
  int cnt;
  List<ListElement> list;
  City city;

  factory GetWeatherDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      GetWeatherDetails(
        cod: json["cod"],
        message: json["message"],
        cnt: json["cnt"],
        list: List<ListElement>.from(
            json["list"].map((x) => ListElement.fromJson(x))),
        city: City.fromJson(json["city"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cod": cod,
        "message": message,
        "cnt": cnt,
        "list": List<dynamic>.from(list.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "city": city.toString(),
      };
}

class City {
  City({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.coord,
    required this.country,
    required this.population,
    required this.timezone,
    required this.sunrise,
    required this.sunset,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  Coord coord;
  String country;
  int population;
  int timezone;
  int sunrise;
  int sunset;

  factory City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => City(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        coord: Coord.fromJson(json["coord"]),
        country: json["country"],
        population: json["population"],
        timezone: json["timezone"],
        sunrise: json["sunrise"],
        sunset: json["sunset"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "coord": coord.toJson(),
        "country": country,
        "population": population,
        "timezone": timezone,
        "sunrise": sunrise,
        "sunset": sunset,
      };
}

class Coord {
  Coord({
    required this.lat,
    required this.lon,
  });

  double lat;
  double lon;

  factory Coord.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Coord(
        lat: json["lat"].toDouble(),
        lon: json["lon"].toDouble(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "lat": lat,
        "lon": lon,
      };
}

class ListElement {
  ListElement({
    required this.dt,
    required this.main,
    required this.weather,
    required this.sys,
    required this.dtTxt,
  });

  int dt;
  Main main;
  List<Weather> weather;
  Sys sys;
  DateTime dtTxt;

  factory ListElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListElement(
        dt: json["dt"],
        main: Main.fromJson(json["main"]),
        weather:
            List<Weather>.from(json["weather"].map((x) => Weather.fromJson(x))),
        sys: Sys.fromJson(json["sys"]),
        dtTxt: DateTime.parse(json["dt_txt"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "dt": dt,
        "main": main.toJson(),
        "weather": List<dynamic>.from(weather.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "sys": sys.toJson(),
        "dt_txt": dtTxt.toIso8601String(),
      };
}

class Main {
  Main({
    required this.temp,
    required this.feelsLike,
    required this.tempMin,
    required this.tempMax,
  });

  double temp;
  double feelsLike;
  double tempMin;
  double tempMax;

  factory Main.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Main(
        temp: json["temp"].toDouble(),
        feelsLike: json["feels_like"].toDouble(),
        tempMin: json["temp_min"].toDouble(),
        tempMax: json["temp_max"].toDouble(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "temp": temp,
        "feels_like": feelsLike,
        "temp_min": tempMin,
        "temp_max": tempMax,
      };
}

class Sys {
  Sys({
    required this.pod,
  });

  String pod;

  factory Sys.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Sys(
        pod: json["pod"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "pod": pod,
      };
}

class Weather {
  Weather({
    required this.id,
    required this.main,
    required this.description,
    required this.icon,
  });

  int id;
  String main;
  String description;
  String icon;

  factory Weather.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Weather(
        id: json["id"],
        main: json["main"],
        description: json["description"],
        icon: json["icon"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "main": main,
        "description": description,
        "icon": icon,
      };
}
```

edited bloc_home (Throw the error, list element not of subtype int):

```
emit(HomeLoadedState(
      activity.city.name.toString(),
      {for (dynamic i in activity.list) {
        print(activity.list[i].main.temp.toInt())
      }},
      activity.list[0].main.temp.toInt(),
      activity.list[0].weather[0].main.toString(),
      {sunRise.hour: sunRise.minute},
      {sunSet.hour: sunSet.minute},
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop through the 'list' array using for-loop and get every temp value. HomeLoadedState
try this:

```
 emit(HomeLoadedState(
    activity.city.name.toString(),
     //for(var i in activity.list){
       //print(activity.list[i].main.temp.toInt()), 
       //here you are passing an int type, but it expecting List
     //}   
    activity.list  
    activity.list[0].main.temp.toInt(),
    activity.list[0].weather[0].main.toString(),
    {sunRise.hour: sunRise.minute},
    {sunSet.hour: sunSet.minute},
  ));
```

Comment: This throws an error: ')' is needed. 

And if I put the loop above emit: ListElement is not a subtype of int

Comment: show me HomeLoadedState function

Comment: I have added it above.

Comment: edited check it

Comment: I already tried that, I'M unsure of how to proceed from here. Because with 'activity.list' alone, I can't get next days temperature from UI.